# How a Query read out Combo Box containing two values

Tags: ms-access

I am using this side a lot. Until this point I found everything I needed to go on with my tasks..

Basically I want to create a database which is based on the Access template Issues.db.
In the database open tasks get stored and get assigned to certain people.
To make it clear there is a Form at the beginning with a combo box to choose a name and since what date the open tasks should be displayed run by a query.

Like in Issue.db the names are stored with an ID as unique Key but only the name is showing.

But my query cannot handle the input from the form. It works fine with the textbook asking for the date (so single value).
The query just needs the ID number which will lead to the correct linked name but I doesn't do anything. There is no error showing but it doesn't give out the right results either.. That the code for the query to get the value. I think it should somehow work over the properties of the Combo box which value to store.

```
Like [Forms]![frmQuerySearch]![cboName]
```

Thanks for help

Johannes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself.
The problem was the handshaking between the form and query. The data wasn't transferred to the query because the data was deleted from memory before giving the data to the query.
Solution was to just hide the form and close the form after the query was run.